# i have a problem with adding a connection string into the web.config file

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, database-connection

I want to add a connection string and give it name..

The connection string belongs to aspnetdb.mdf which was created when i added my CreateUserWizard.

This is its connection string:

> `Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename="D:\Documents and Settings\Dima\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite10\App_Data\ASPNETDB.MDF";Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True`

Now when i add it to the config file:

```
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="YourGuruDB" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename="D:\Documents and Settings\Dima\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite10\App_Data\ASPNETDB.MDF";Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

it shows me weird line underneath of part of the string which prevents it from being executed..

I also dont understand the connection between the membership config and the database

```
    <membership defaultProvider="MyMembershipProvider">
```

What is this provider? Shouldnt it be .NET Framework provider? Same as the aspnetDB

Also why do i see red Xes on the databases i created/and the system created whenever i open my server explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try taking out the double quotes within the connectionString="" attribute.

Comment: Use single quotes instead, if your sub-string contains spaces.

Comment: what about the red X that appears on my database that is in my Server explorer